# Grafana, write a simple plugin, without using grunt or whatever

Tags: javascript, plugins, grafana

Good day all. I'm new to Grafana and we adopted it very recently at work.

I'm willing to create a plugin, I need to load a simple external js library and fire it in a Grafana panel, nothing extreme.

**First problem**: I don't want to use any building library (grunt or whatever), I just want to write the plugin javascript, I don't want to redistribute it. Where do I write the code?
Am I right to write the code I want to execute in the `data/plugins/myplugin/dist/` folder? (I'm trying to follow the steps at Grafana Docs, but they are unclear as they talk about building and install scripts which I don't like to use).

**Second Problem**: Seems like that if I use the dist/ folder, the plugin get executed. Now, I'd like to import a external.js library into it, the external library will take care of display the data as I like.

into my myplugin_ctrl.js I write this:

```
System.register(['app/plugins/sdk', 'lodash', './css/clock-panel.css!','./libs/datamaps'], function (_export, _context) {
  var PanelCtrl, _, _createClass, panelDefaults, ClockCtrl;
```

As you may notice, I've used the clock plugin that is used into the how-to at Grafana.

I'd like to import `'./libs/datamaps'`, what I managed to do is having this error upon adding the panel to a dashboard:

```
Plugin component error Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://127.0.0.1:3000/data/plugins/test-panel/libs/datamaps
  Loading http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/plugins/test-panel/clock_ctrl.js
```

What I'm doing wrong? Where do the `datamap.js` should be? Or how do I can import it into Grafana plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you really need to solve this with a plugin, as I couldn't find any mention about data retrieval from any data sources in your question. Also, I'm not yet very familiar with Grafana plugin development, but I was able to solve one JavaScript related problem without a need to write a plugin.

What I did: I put a `Text` element in `html` mode on a dashboard and inserted a `<script>...</script>` section as well as some HTML code. This worked until I updated Grafana to a newer version, where they started to block this due to security reasons. After configuring `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` setting `disable_sanitize_html = true` in section `[panels]`, I made it work again. You could do this, too, but keep in mind that this is a security risk, because the dashboards now allow to inject any kind of malicious JavaScript code.

[See also this Grafana reference page for scripted dashboards](https://grafana.com/docs/reference/scripting/).